# What is the FeatureKey enumeration of the UtilElementType and is there an equivalent in Dynamics AX 2009?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics, axapta

I've downloaded some code off the net which includes the `UtilElementType::FeatureKey` enumeration. This does not exist in Dynamics AX 2009.

What was its purpose? 
More importantly, is there an equivalent I need to include in the code instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UtilElementType::FeatureKey was used in AX 3.0 and prior, but [removed in 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa654810%28v=ax.10%29.aspx) and later. It was a mix of UtilElementType::SecurityKey and UtilElementType::ConfigurationKey.

You may substitute any or one of these.